# On which partition is my bootloader installed?

Tags: partitioning, bootloader

How can I check on which partition Ubuntu installed my bootloader from within Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Where `sda` is the disk you want to check the partitions, one of them should be listed as boot partition, if you have more then 1 disk there can be other partitions marked as boot, the next logical disk is `sdb` followed by `sdc`, etc.

If you have more then a disk and more than 1 partition is marked as boot the booting will be determined by the selected boot device in your BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by installed.  Grub places some files in the /boot directory, which usually is on the same partition as /.  It also embeds its core image to the Master Boot Record of the drive, and the following several sectors that are not part of any partition, so in that sense, it is not installed to any partition, but rather to the whole disk.

You can check the output of `df` to see what partitions you have mounted where.  If there is no entry for /boot, then it is part of the root filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is GUI way of doing it

**1- Open Disks**

[image]

**2 - Click on each partition**

See the `partition type`. If the partition is bootable it will be marked as `Bootable`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## The bootloader

### BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode

- In the old MSDOS partition table with the MBR (Master Boot Record), the bootloader is installed into the first mibibyte of the drive, and the first partition starts behind that 'unallocated drive space'.
- In the new GUID partition table, GPT, the bootloader is installed into a small (typically 1 mibibyte) partition with a **`bios_grub`** flag and no file system.

### UEFI mode

In UEFI mode the bootloader is located in the EFI System Partition, ESP, which is usually a few hundred mibibytes with a FAT file system. The ESP should have a **`boot`** flag, and can also have an **`esp`** flag. (The UEFI system does not look for a bootloader at the head end of the drive.)

In Ubuntu the ESP is often mounted at the mountpoint `/boot/efi` and can be identified via the command

```
df -h /boot/efi
```

Otherwise you can identify the ESP with this `parted` command

```
sudo parted -ls
```

or if there are problems with `parted` with the following commands

```
sudo lsblk -o name,fstype,label,mountpoint,partflags,partlabel
sudo fdisk -lu
```

## The grub files

The grub files (`grub.cfg`, the hardware drivers etc) belong to the bootloader and are located in the directory `/boot` (as seen, when booted into the system). *You find the partition with the following command line*,

```
df -h /boot
```

## Link

See this link for more details,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of the [boot_info_script](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/).

There you will see where the Grub binaries and configuration files were installed.